# How to read lines into cell array at the matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I want to read a regular text file into cell array at the matlab. How can i do that ?

I don't want any formatting. Reading as literals.

Thank you.

It will be row based array like 100x1

```
example of reading : dd = {1;2;3}
```

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  That is, stuffing the tag list full of the same words you use in your question and question title does not help people to find your question.  Tags stand alone, meaning tagging with `read`, `text`, `file`, `lines` does not mean that you are trying to read lines from a text file.   Please select tags with care.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `textscan`, so to have one cell element per line:

```
fid = fopen('myFile.ext');
allData = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');

% allData{1} is a nLines-by-1 cell array with the lines of the file as text
```

Comment: thanks but not working as i wanted. the alldata is also 1x1 cell. and inside of it there is the data i wanted. the alldata need to be 100x1 cell array